# Nuxt : n2 is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt 3 and I have an TypeError like this :

```
Uncaught TypeError: n2 is not a function
```

I have a button calling my function toggleSelectRow with a @click.prevent

And here is the function :

```
const toggleSelectRow = (keyword) => {
    if (keywordsSelected.value.find((kw) => kw.uid_kw === keyword.uid_kw) && props.keywords.length > 1) {
        keywordsSelected.value = []
        nuxtApp.$bus.$emit('filter-from-list', '');
    } else {
        keywordsSelected.value = [keyword]
        nuxtApp.$bus.$emit('filter-from-list', keyword.uid_kw);
  }
}
```

Here is the receiver part :

```
$bus.$on('filter-from-list', (newKeyword) => {   filters.keyword = (props.keywords.find((kw) => kw.uid_kw === newKeyword)) ? newKeyword : null   if (!filters.keyword) {
    refreshNuxtData('average-keyword-position');
    return;   }

  fetchKeywordPosition({ keyword: newKeyword }); });
```

nuxtApp is defined above with : `const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();`

I think my problem come from the emit but I don't know why because if I refresh the page, it will work.

**Fixing test 1**

I tried to use a declared function in the receiver component like this :

```
function filterFromList(newKeyword){
  filters.keyword = (props.keywords.find((kw) => kw.uid_kw === newKeyword)) ? newKeyword : null
  if (!filters.keyword) {
    refreshNuxtData('average-keyword-position');
    return;
  }

  fetchKeywordPosition({ keyword: newKeyword });
}
```

to call it like this : `$bus.$on('filter-from-list', filterFromList);` but I still have the same error so I think the problem must come from the sender/receiver.

Comment: On the other side of the `$bus` receiveing the `filter-from-list` event, what are you calling ? I've faced same error on `vue.js` with `mitt` when defining `mitt.on('event', something)` with something which was not a function...

Comment: I call a function, the weird thing is if i reload the page, the function is well called

Comment: Could you share the "receiver part" ?

Comment: I added it to the original message

Comment: Thanks. Could you try with getting the all function in a vue.js method (called `mymethod` for example) and then write `$bus.$on('filter-from-list', this.mymethod)` ? Hope it'll help

Comment: It's from another component so I can't call this.method

Comment: But couldnt you externalize the code in a method in the component including the $on ? I had the exact same problem with `mitt` in vue.js and fixed it by declaring a not anonymous function call on the receiver side

Comment: Like this : ```$bus.$on('filter-from-list', (newKeyword) => {
  filterFromList(newKeyword);
});``` ?

Comment: Nope. More `$bus.$on('filter-from-list', this.mymethod)` with `mymethod` being a function with one arg `newKeyword` which would do the same thing as your inner anonymous function

Comment: I tried with a not anonymous function call as you said but I still face the same issue. I tried to log the newKeyword at the start of the function but same thing. The problem must come from the sernder/receiver

Comment: I'll try to reproduce your error. Hope I'll be able to help

Comment: Hey ! I take ou back on this account. I tought I lost this one so I created a new one. When you try to reproduce we can maybe go to a private discussion not to spam this question ?

Comment: If you know how to do it, please proceed, I'll answer when available. Also find this [article](https://www.danielknows.com/post/how-to-use-emit-nuxt-3/) which might help (and describe more what I wanted you to setup). I think I lack of context to help you more on this (like more full component code).

Comment: The article you sent is exactly what I've done in my project. I will update my ask tomorrow with the full script from my 2 components.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a scope issue.

try to bind the `this` manually in your emitter

```
$bus.$on('filter-from-list', filterFromList.bind(this));
```

---

However, nuxt3 has a better way to handle the global events: [Lifecycle Hooks](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/hooks).

you can custom a hook

```
// in senders
// before
nuxtApp.$bus.$emit('filter-from-list', '');
// after
nuxtApp.callHook('filter-from-list', '');

// in receivers
// before
nuxtApp.$bus.$on('filter-from-list', (newKeyword) => {});
// after
nuxtApp.hook('filter-from-list', (newKeyword) => {});
```

at last, extend the types of `#app`

```
declare module '#app' {
    interface RuntimeNuxtHooks {
        'filter-from-list': (string) => HookResult;
    }
}
```